# Get drag-n-drop qtreewidget items - Python

Tags: python, pyside, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

Is there a way I can get the items being drag/dropped and their destination parent?

In an ideal scenario what I want to happen is once the **dropEvent** finishes, it prints the qtreewidgetitems which were moved, as well as the new parent which the items were moved to. The parent would either be the qtreewidget itself or another qtreewidgetitem depending on where the drop happened.

Can someone help me out here please?

Below is the code i have so far.

[image]

```
# Imports
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg

class TreeNodeItem( QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem ):
    def __init__( self, parent, name="" ):
        super( TreeNodeItem, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.setText( 0, name )
        self.stuff = "Custom Names - " + str(name)

class TreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setItemsExpandable(True)
        self.setAnimated(True)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

    # def dropEvent(self, event):
    #     print "finished"
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        return_val = super( TreeWidget, self ).dropEvent( event )
        print ("Drop finished")
        d = event.mimeData()
        print d, event.source()
        return return_val

# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ExampleWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # formatting
        self.resize(250, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        # widget - passes treewidget
        self.itemList = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.itemList = TreeWidget()

        headers = [ "Items" ]
        self.itemList.setColumnCount( len(headers) )
        self.itemList.setHeaderLabels( headers )            

        # layout Grid - row/column/verticalpan/horizontalspan
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.itemList, 0,0,1,1)

        # display
        self.show()

    # Functions
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print "closed"


    def showEvent(self, event):
        print "open"
        for i in xrange(20):
            TreeNodeItem( parent=self.itemList , name=str(i) )

# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ExampleWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a View/Model approach. 
Decoding the 'application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist' will only return the item dragged, and the dropMimeData isn't used in the QTreeWidget.

Look here for an example.
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Handling%20Qt's%20internal%20item%20MIME%20type